# Performance - jQuery.data vs jQuery().data

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

Take a look at this test:

http://jsperf.com/jquery-data-vs-jqueryselection-data

Why is the first one much faster ? Why doesn't the jquery team update the 2nd one to use the same code as the first?

Comment: It does use the same code. The additional overhead is due to the library having to tell the difference between a one-argument and two-argument call, and between calling with a property object and a simple pair of strings. This is all pretty obvious from the source code.

Comment: it doesn't looks like it's the same code- https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/data.js

Comment: Is that 2.0 code? Wow, it's a lot different from the 1.10 code.

Comment: Your jsperf test is using version 1.9.

Comment: _"Why doesn't the jquery team update the 2nd one to use the same code as the first?"_ You'd have to ask the jQuery team.

Comment: Out of curiosity, the same test for 2.x: http://jsperf.com/jquery2-data-vs-fn-data.